# Derivative of a function with condition

Tags: derivatives

Consider a function 
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}  xy, & |x|<|y| \\ 0, & \mathrm{else} \end{cases} $$
Let's say, we are going to compute
$f_{,x}(0,0), f_{,y}(0,0), f_{,xy}(0,0)$ and $f_{,yx}(0,0)$ in point $(0,0)$.
Important note: I took the liberty of physical/relativistic notation of partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as $f_{,x}$.
How do I do that?
Actually, this is an example of non-interchangeability of second derivatives, my maths teacher has this in his book, stating that
$$f_{,xy}(0,0)=0\, \mathrm{and}\, f_{,yx}(0,0)=1$$
however, I do not quite understand how he got into a conclusion that it should be this way(there is no commentary on computing it). I presumed, that the condition stays even after the process of differentiation and since $x=y=0$, then those results should be the same. Am I wrong?
Anyway, we can consider also a function
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}xy\sin(x^2-y^2)^{-1}, & \mathrm{for}\, (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\ 0, & \mathrm{for}\, (x,y)=0 \end{cases}$$
and compute $f_{,x}(0,0), f_{,y}(0,0), f_{,xy}(0,0)$ and $f_{,yx}(0,0)$ where they exist.
How do I do that?

Comment: Your array definition of $f$ can be written instead with the `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` dedicated environment, just so that you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go back to definitions. You need
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}h = 0 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) &= \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}k = 0 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y) &= \frac{\partial (xy)}{\partial x} = x \quad (y\ne 0) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0) &= \frac{\partial (0)}{\partial x} = 0.
\end{align*}
Now write down 
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Big|_{x=0}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)\right)$$
and
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0) = \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big|_{y=0}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)\right)$$
and compute.

I'll let you attack the second problem now. :)